# Android: ScrollView and drawing cache?

Tags: android, caching, listview, scroll, scrollview

Are the views that get scrolled off of ScrollView automatically cached by the drawing cache?  I'm not quite sure i understand the API documentation.

Answer (score 10):

`int PERSISTENT_ALL_CACHES` Used to indicate that all drawing caches should be kept in memory.

`int PERSISTENT_ANIMATION_CACHE` Used to indicate that the animation drawing cache should be kept in memory.

`int PERSISTENT_NO_CACHE` Used to indicate that no drawing cache should be kept in memory.

`int PERSISTENT_SCROLLING_CACHE` Used to indicate that the scrolling drawing cache should be kept in memory.

---

Use these in

```
public void setPersistentDrawingCache (int drawingCacheToKeep)
```

which indicates what types of drawing caches should be kept in memory after they have been created.

---

**Example**

```
 setPersistentDrawingCache(ViewGroup.PERSISTENT_SCROLLING_CACHE);
 setAlwaysDrawnWithCacheEnabled(true); // call this method 
 //to start (true) and stop (false) using the drawing cache
 //when you perform performance sensitive operations, like scrolling or animating.
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  So if I'm understanding this correctly, the drawing cache is just used to render off screen bitmaps at the expense of more memory, right?

Comment: Yes exactly.. I hope you could do some tests.. And give us some results.